# Validity checking won't work in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a simple task list where the user can add and delete tasks at will but I am having a hard time with the delete function. I need to validate the user input to check if it's a number or not then proceed to delete that element from the array. When I test my program, even if I input a number, I'll get the alert saying that my input is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

```js
(function(){
    
 // Variable that stores the tasks:
    var tasks = []; 

 // Function called when the form is submitted.
 // Function adds a task to the global array.
    function addTask() {
        'use strict';
        var task = document.getElementById('task');
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var message = '';

        if (task.value) {
            tasks.push(task.value);
            message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
            }
            message += '</ol>';
            output.innerHTML = message;        
        } // End of task.value IF.

     // Return false to prevent submission:
        return false;

    } // End of addTask() function.
 
 function deleteTask(){
  'use strict';
  var deleteElement = prompt('Which task would you like to delete?', 'Enter task number');
  
  var message = '';
  
  //check validity of input
  if( (typeof deleteElement == 'number') ){
   
   var index = tasks.index0f(deleteElement);
   if (index > -1){
    tasks.splice(index, 1);
   }
   
   /*document.getElementById('output') = '';
    message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
            }
            message += '</ol>';
            output.innerHTML = message;*/
  }
  else{
   alert('Input must be a number');
  }
  return false;
 }

    // Initial setup:
    function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('add_task').onclick = addTask;
  document.getElementById('delete').onclick = deleteTask;
    } // End of init() function.
    window.onload = init;

})();
```

```css
/*
dark blue: 212B40
gray-blue: 547B97
gray-green-blue: BADCDD
light-green: C2E078
*/
/*
dark blue: 1B1D26
dark green: 425955
gray-green: 778C7A
off-white: F1F2D8
tan: BFBD9F
*/

body{
font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color: #1b1d26;
background-color: #f1f2d8;
}
p, h1, form, button{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
.spacer{clear:both; height:1px;}
/* ----------- My Form ----------- */
form{
margin:0 auto;
width:400px;
padding:14px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border:solid 2px #425955;
}

/* ----------- stylized ----------- */
 h1 {
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:8px;
}
h2 {
 clear: both;
}
 p{
font-size:11px;
color:#666666;
margin-bottom:20px;
border-bottom:solid 1px #BFBD9F;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
 label{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
float:left;
}
 .small{
color:#666666;
display:block;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:normal;
text-align:right;
width:140px;
}
 select{
float:left;
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #BFBD9F;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
}
 input{
float:left;
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #BFBD9F;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
}
#add_task, #delete{
clear:both;
margin-left:150px;
width:125px;
height:31px;
background:#F1F2D8;
text-align:center;
line-height:20px;
color:#000000;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
}
#output {
 clear:both;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 6.5 - task.html -->
   <!-- <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">-->
    <div id="form"
        <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
            <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
            <input type="button" value="Add a task" id="add_task">
   <input type="button" value="Delete task" id="delete">
      <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
 </div>
    <!--</form>-->
    <script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you check if number  exists in array ?also array index starts with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if I input a number, I'll get the alert saying that my input is invalid.

Prompt give you the entered text in string format, hence that is of type String. 
That is not the correct way to check that user entered a number or not.

Correct ways is, have utility function

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

And then check

```
if( (isNumber(deleteElement)){
---
```

Comment: Just wondering, when would you use 'typeof' as a conditional? I'm new to j.s so I'm still learning about all this

Answer (score 0):

You could also try wrapping the number in a parseInt(). This should make in a number value just in case its being saved as a string in your array.